# C# parsing text data line by line

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, text

I have a problem with my project, let me explain a moment here and I need some expert guidance here because i am new to programming.
I have a data in notepad like this:

```
10192 20351 30473 40499 50449 60234    
10192 20207 30206 40203 50205 60226    
10192 20252 30312 40376 50334 60252
```

it's 26 line of data, but I only show 3 line just for example. Here's some rule sort by it's priority:

-I only want to read the text file then extract the number. Example : 10192 20351 so on.

-I have 6 column of ListView and I want to display each line of number in it's column

> Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6

```
10192   | 20351   | 30473  | 40499  |50449  | 60234
```

-off course if possible, The first 2 digit of each 5 digit of number is a unique code, all i want is just 3 last digit. For example: 192 351 473 499 234. so it's going to be mod by 10.000 for each number.

I guess i'm confusing alot of you guys, sorry, here's my current code

private delegate void UpdateUiTextDelegate(String Text);
        private void serial_DataRecieved(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Collecting the characters received to our 'buffer' (string).
            string received_data;
            received_data = serial.ReadExisting();
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new UpdateUiTextDelegate(WriteData), received_data);
        }

```
    private void WriteData(String Text)
    {
        if (bufferData != "" || Text[0] == '1')
            bufferData += Text;
        if (bufferData.Length >= 35)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Rads\Desktop\Training06.txt", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(bufferData);
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add(bufferData);
            bufferData = "";
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //Browse .txt file
    private void Browse_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        dlg.Filter = "Text document (.txt)|*.txt";

        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            textBox.Text = filename;
        }
    }

    private void Parsing_String(string filename)
    {
        List<Row> list = new List<Row>();

        foreach (String str in File.ReadLines(filename))
        {
            String[] strCols = str.Split(Convert.ToChar(" "));
            list.Add(new Row()
            {
                Column1 = strCols[0].Substring(2),
                Column2 = strCols[1].Substring(2),
                Column3 = strCols[2].Substring(2),
                Column4 = strCols[3].Substring(2),
                Column5 = strCols[4].Substring(2),
                Column6 = strCols[5].Substring(2),


            });
        }

        dg.ItemsSource = list;
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public string Column1 { get; set; }
        public string Column2 { get; set; }
        public string Column3 { get; set; }
        public string Column4 { get; set; }
        public string Column5 { get; set; }
        public string Column6 { get; set; }

    }
```

XAML Code

```
<Window x:Class="SamplingData.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="368" Width="401" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

<TabControl Height="332" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380">
    <TabItem Header="Sampling" Name="Sampling">
        <Grid>
            <Label Content="DATA RECEIVED" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Button Content="Connect" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="264,6,0,0" Name="ConnectButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Connect_Comms" />
            <ListBox Height="222" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,37,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="329" />
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Training" Name="tabItem1">
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="Training" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="243,28,0,0" Name="Train_Btn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
            <Button Content="Browse" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="243,6,0,0" Name="Browse_btn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Browse_btn_Click" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,7,0,0" Name="textBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="231" Background="{x:Null}"></TextBox>
            <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="507,76,0,0" Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,57,0,0" DataContext="{Binding}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column1}" Header="Column 1"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column2}" Header="Column 2"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column3}" Header="Column 3"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column4}" Header="Column 4"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column5}" Header="Column 5"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column6}" Header="Column 6"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

thanks a lot if someone can help me..

Comment: What is your actual question? I see a list of requirements but nothing explaining where you are having a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** ADDED Row variable as suggested by Ash:

Given that you did not specify to which object you are going to write the data I asssume it's a datarow named Row:

```
private void Parsing_String(string filename)    
{
    DataTable dt = CreateDataTable();
    foreach (String str in File.ReadLines(filename))
    {
      String[] strCols = str.Split(Convert.ToChar(" "));
      DataRow Row = dt.NewRow(); //Where dt is a DataTable
      for (int i =0; i < strCols.length; i++)
      {
           Row[i] = strCols[i].Substring(2); //This will start reading from the third character
      }
      dt.Rows.Add(Row);
     }
      listView1.ItemsSource = dt.Rows;
}

//**EDIT**: Just in case you don't have a datatable and you want to create a small one:

public DataTable CreateDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        new string[] { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4", "Column 5", "Column 6" }
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(c => { dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c)); });
        return dt;
    }
```

**EDIT:** Last Try (Ignore code above):

```
    private void Parsing_String(string filename)
    {
        List<Row> list = new List<Row>();

        foreach (String str in File.ReadLines(filename))
        {
            String[] strCols = str.Split(Convert.ToChar(" "));
            list.Add(new Row() 
            {
                Column1 = strCols[0].Substring(2),
                Column2 = strCols[1].Substring(2),
                Column3 = strCols[2].Substring(2),
                Column4 = strCols[3].Substring(2),
                Column5 = strCols[4].Substring(2),
                Column6 = strCols[5].Substring(2)
            });
        }

        dg.ItemsSource = list;
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public string Column1 { get; set; }
        public string Column2 { get; set; }
        public string Column3 { get; set; }
        public string Column4 { get; set; }
        public string Column5 { get; set; }
        public string Column6 { get; set; }
    }
```

And then in your xaml:

If you want to specify custom headers you will have to change it so that it does not autogenerate columns but uses bindings i.e.:

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column1}" Header="Column 1"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column2}" Header="Column 2"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column3}" Header="Column 3"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column4}" Header="Column 4"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column5}" Header="Column 5"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Column6}" Header="Column 6"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**Edit** This will calculate the first column total

```
protected int CalculateFirstColumnTotal(List<Row> list)
{
    int total = 0;
    foreach (Row row in list)
      total += int.Parse(row.Column1);
}
```

**EDIT**:

You are never actually calling the Parsing_String method, add the below line to the browse method:

```
private void Browse_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
{
    //Existing Code
    Parsing_String(textBox.Text);  //Add this line to the last line of the method.
}
```

Comment: Good other than the Row[i] part. I'm guessing there should be another variable outside the for loop to increment the row. Otherwise for each row in the file 6 rows will be created.

Comment: sorry, it's going to be listbox with 6 columns. i'll give it a try.

Comment: listview not list box. sorry for confusing. I'm using C# Wpf.

Comment: where i can find data table? because i'm using c# 2010 and i can't find any datatable in my toolbox?

Comment: add a using statement to the top of your code: using System.Data; I've changed the code so that it will bind to your listview

Comment: even better, just change your listview to a DataGrid and it should work as expected

Comment: data grid must use database right? all i need is my .txt file.

Comment: i try your code, no error at all but my listview still not show the data.

Comment: Ok, You need to setup the listview, will add xaml to code now. Nope, datagrid does not need to use database

Comment: great maybe datagrid will works great isn't it? thanks a lot anyway i dont know how to thank you.

Comment: Ok, have a look at the last entry, that is all the code you need, this got out of hand very quickly :-)

Comment: sorry but the datagrid still doesn't show any number yet. the code is oke although.

Comment: my dg.ItemsSource is not blue still black. means it's doesn't work right? Am I doing something wrong here if you tested the code and work but i cant get it work?

Comment: oh and 1 more question. I will use the number for some mathematics. Can I use the number on the first line to put in my mathematics calculation? then after that read the 2nd line and put the number again to my calculation?

Comment: Hmmm strange, can you paste your code (just the code you copied from me of your code behind(c#) as well as xaml? And then also put this line of code before the last line(dg.ItemsSource = list;): MessageBox.Show(list.First().Column1);

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are asking with regards to the calculation question, but you now have a list of all the values you can access. I will give a small example in the code based on how I think you asked the question:

Comment: I edit the code above take a look. What I intend to do is I read the number - show it then convert the string to integer - then use the number to put on some mathematics calculation. What I think is, If i can show the data to C# app, then i can use it on calculation.

Comment: Ok, see the addition I made to my code, you need to call the Parse_String method for it to be executed...

Comment: See if this works, then afterwards mark the answer as complete and create a new question with regards to the number calculation, I will then have a look at that as this question is becoming a bit long winded...

Comment: calling the method seems not working, it says the 'filename' does not exist in this context. and where i should put the protected void? anywhere?coz it cant

Comment: Ignore the protected void, that was just to show you where to put it, the only line you need to add is Parsing_String(textBox.Text); Notice that I've changed it from filename to textBox.Text

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need Regex at all. You just need [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) by line and by space.

```
string[] lines = data.Split(Enviroment.NewLine);
```

For each line, you can get the fields by splitting the line by space.

```
string[] fields = line.Split(' ');
```

Comment: line.Split(' '); should be lines.Split(' ');

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko : No, line is an item of lines array.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
var result = from row in theFileAsString.Split('\n')
             select new {
                Columns = row.Split(' ').Select(s => s.Substring(2))
             }
```

There you'll have an `IEnumerable` with items each having a property `Columns` containing strings with the data.

Very untested though, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is probably overkill, but you mentioned that you wanted to put the data into a listview (perhaps a datagrid?), in which case, you might want to get the data into some sort of object form. It really depends on what you're actually going to do with the data once you've got it.

Working under the assumption that once you've got the data you'll want to manipulate it or do something more with it, try something like this - you should be able to put it straight into into a new console app and run it.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = @"c:\test.txt";

            // Because you're working with a small file, we'll just read all the lines into memory
            List<LineData> processedLines = new List<LineData>();
            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filename))
            {
                processedLines.Add(new LineData(line));
            }

            // Write out the line data to the console to prove that it has been read
            foreach (var processedLine in processedLines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", 
                    processedLine.Column1, 
                    processedLine.Column2,
                    processedLine.Column3,
                    processedLine.Column4,
                    processedLine.Column5,
                    processedLine.Column6);
            }
        }
    }

    public class LineData
    {
        public LineData(string line)
        {
            // Regex basically means find two digits ("Prefix") followed by 3 digits ("Value")
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<Prefix>\d{2})(?<Value>\d{3})");
            var lineMatches = regex.Matches(line);
            if (lineMatches.Count != 6)
            {
                // You should really be throwing your own exception type...
                throw new Exception("Expected 6 columns!");
            }

            this.Column1 = this.ExtractMatchData(lineMatches[0]);
            this.Column2 = this.ExtractMatchData(lineMatches[1]);
            this.Column3 = this.ExtractMatchData(lineMatches[2]);
            this.Column4 = this.ExtractMatchData(lineMatches[3]);
            this.Column5 = this.ExtractMatchData(lineMatches[4]);
            this.Column6 = this.ExtractMatchData(lineMatches[5]);
        }

        private string ExtractMatchData(Match match)
        {
            return match.Groups["Value"].Value;
        }

        public string Column1 { get; set; }
        public string Column2 { get; set; }
        public string Column3 { get; set; }
        public string Column4 { get; set; }
        public string Column5 { get; set; }
        public string Column6 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. it's not a small file afterall. 3 lines i put it's only a sample. I have 26 line number like that. but i give it a try.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things 26 lines is small :)

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var stream = File.Open(this.filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    var data = reader.ReadLine();
    while (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(data))
    {
        string[] columns = data.Split(' ');
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", columns[0], columns[1],));
        data = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use regex for this.

```
var data = @"10192 20351 30473 40499 50449 60234
10192 20207 30206 40203 50205 60226
10192 20252 30312 40376 50334 60252";

var result = from line in data.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             let splitted = line.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             select splitted.Select(s => s.Substring(2));
```

or for files

```
using System.IO; // In the top

var result = from line in File.ReadLines("path")
             let splitted = line.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             select splitted.Select(s => s.Substring(2));
```

`result` will now contain a sequence of sequences of strings (where the first two characters are removed). This version works with both Unix and Windows line-breaks. And it also removes additional whitespace which might cause other answers to fail.

Comment: can i access each of number that already split in array with this code?

Comment: @Reza Hi, I'm not sure what you mean. But you can convert the result to an array with `var asArray = result.ToArray();` and then access the individual rows by index.